# Behavior of the nvme tool with respect to protection information?

Tags: nvme

Environment: Debian Bullseye, up to date at the time of writing, nvme-cli 1.12

I am totally new to NVMe and currently try to configure an NVMe SSD correctly. As far as I can tell, I don't need metadata, but **I would like to use the T10-PI protection information.** I have got two questions regarding this subject:

**First, I'd like to know how to find out whether that protection has been enabled for a certain device or namespace at all.** I know that I can enable or disable the T10-PI when formatting the device or namespace, but I can't figure out how to get its current status. I have read a good part of the manual pages of the various `nvme` commands, and also have tried to make sense of the NVMe specification to a certain level, but to no avail. I just seem to be unable to spot it.

I am having that problem only with that specific setting; with other settings that are of interest to me, it didn't take too long to find out how to read their current status or value.

**Second, I am not sure how to enable that protection.** Theoretically, and from reading `man nvme-format`, it is clear. I just have to add the `-i <n>` parameter to the format command to have something like that:

```
nvme format /dev/nvme0 -l 3 -i 1
```

The disk in question provides 6 LBA modes, mode `3` being the one I want: 4096 bytes per sector, no metadata; hence the `-l 3` parameter. `-i 1` turns on the T10-PI.

When I issue the command above, it gets executed without error message. Afterwards, `smartctl -x /dev/nvme0` shows that the current LBA size is now `4096`; `nvme id-ns /dev/nvme0n1` confirms that mode `3` is in use as expected. So far, so good.

But the following is very suspicious:

```
root@gaia ~/scripts # nvme list
Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     PHFT640100G7800CGN   INTEL SSDPEDMD800G4                      1         800.17  GB / 800.17  GB      4 KiB +  0 B   8DV10171
```

Under `Format`, it shows `4 KiB +  0 B`. Why? As far as I have understood, the T10-PI needs at least 8 bytes of metadata per LBA. Therefore, I am unsure what actually happens.

Does `nvme format /dev/nvme0 -l 3 -i 1` just leave the PI disabled (because there is no metadata, and therefore no space for it)? Or is the PI enabled, but `nvme list` shows only the "real" metadata size (not including the "implicit" bytes which are needed for the PI)?

Do I need to use `-l 4` instead of `-l 3` with `nvme format`? `-l 4` means 4096 bytes LBA size + 8 bytes metadata. If I need to use `-l 4`, why does `nvme format -l 3 -i 1` not throw an error due to wrong command line parameters (we can't turn on T10-PI if we don't have metadata)?